ansible-builder doesn't create the introspect.py script
I'm building an execution environment with ansible-builder. Every time I run it I get this error:

#24 0.269 /usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/output/scripts/introspect.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
#24 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c $PYCMD /output/scripts/introspect.py introspect --user-pip=requirements.txt --user-bindep=bindep.txt --write-bindep=/tmp/src/bindep.txt --write-pip=/tmp/src/requirements.txt]: exit code: 2

I assume introspect.py is related to the collections dependency introspection.
For context, I'm running this in a custom Docker container I built, so it's possible maybe I installed ansible-builder incorrectly? But I'm not sure. Here's the Dockerfile:
FROM docker.io/docker

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apk add --update --no-cache jq python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m venv .venv
RUN . .venv/bin/activate
RUN .venv/bin/pip3 install ansible-builder
RUN ln .venv/bin/ansible-builder /usr/bin/ansible-builder

I verified that ansible-builder create is creating the _build/scripts/introspect.py script which gets copied in by the Dockerfile:
COPY _build/scripts/ /output/scripts/

It's working when I build the EE from the CLI but when it builds in a CI pipeline using the above container, I get the error.
Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

I stumbled into the same error and have successfully worked my way through it.  I figured I'd share my discoveries.
Recently ansible-builder has underwent an upgrade making version 3.1.0 available.
Without seeing your execution-environment.yml file I would suspect that you are still using the format.

version: 1

I would recommend using the version 3 format which looks something like this:
---
version: 3
images:
  base_image:
    name: registry.redhat.io/ansible-automation-platform-24/ee-minimal-rhel8:latest

dependencies:
  galaxy: requirements.yml

options:
  package_manager_path: /usr/bin/microdnf

A solid reference can be found here: [https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/unlocking-efficiency-harnessing-the-capabilities-of-ansible-builder-3.0].  Take heed of the options. I missed it the first time, before I found the above link better explaining it.
Something else that I might add.  Verify the version of python that your ansible.cfg is using and build a python venv who's version is the same. python3.9 appears to be my preferred engine.
